# Setting Bxslider to load different images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

Hello everyone and thank you for your time.
I made a Menu with 2 images.
I want Bxslider to change and show different images each time someone clicks 1 of the 2 "Menu images"
So the idea i had is to hide 1 of the 2 bxsliders and swap when i click menu any ideas how i can do that?

Here is what i managed to make so far

Here is the 2 images menu:

```
    <div class="Menu1">
    <div class="Menu1_1"> <a href="a"class="reload-slider1" ><img src="images/menu2/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_menu2_2_1.jpg" width="593" height="100" onClick="changeImage4()"  id="toChange4" ></a>
    </div>
  <div class="Menu1_1" >
  <img src="images/menu2/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_menu2_1_2.jpg" width="596" height="100" onClick="changeImage5()" id="toChange5">
    </div>
```

Here are the scripts for the Bxslider:

```
<---BxSlider----->




       <script>
var slider = $('.bxslider1').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal'
});


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
  infiniteLoop: false,
  hideControlOnEnd: true
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bxslider3').bxSlider({
  infiniteLoop: false,
  hideControlOnEnd: true
    });
});
</script>
<script>
    $('.reload-slider1').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 $('.bxslider1').append('<li><img src="images/slider/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_v1_1.jpg"></li>');
  $('.bxslider1').append('<li><img src="images/slider/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_v1_2.jpg"></li>');

    slider.reloadSlider();
});



    $('.reload-slider2').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.bxslider2').append('<li><img src="images/slider/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_v2_1.jpg"></li>');
  $('.bxslider2').append('<li><img src="images/slider/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_v2_2.jpg"></li>');
   $('.bxslider2').prepend('<li><img src="images/slider/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_v1_1.jpg"></li>');
    $('.bxslider2').prepend('<li><img src="images/slider/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_v1_2.jpg"></li>');
  slider.reloadSlider();
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML appears invalid:

```
<div class="Menu1">
    <div class="Menu1_1">
        <img src="images/menu2/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_menu2_2_1.jpg" width="593" height="100" onClick="changeImage4()" id="toChange4 ; reload-slider">
    </div>
    <div class="Menu1_1">
        <img src="images/menu2/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_menu2_1_2.jpg" width="596" height="100" onClick="changeImage5()" id="toChange5 ; reload-slider2">
    </div>
```

It contains invalid ID, and probably that is why `document.getElementById()` is not working for you. Change the id of the img tags:

```
    <div class="Menu1">
    <div class="Menu1_1">
        <img src="images/menu2/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_menu2_2_1.jpg" width="593" height="100" onClick="changeImage4()" id="toChange4">
    </div>
    <div class="Menu1_1">
        <img src="images/menu2/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_menu2_1_2.jpg" width="596" height="100" onClick="changeImage5()" id="toChange5">
    </div>
```

Comment: I need 2 seperate IDs how i can do that

Comment: In your img tag, you have given Id as "toChange4 ; reload-slider" and "toChange5 ; reload-slider" which are invalid . Also, ID doesn't work the way classes work. Elements should have single unique ID

Comment: changeImage4 with changeImage5 arent differend IDs? so i connect classes with javascript? I want 2 things to be done when i click an image tochange other images and to reload the slider how i can do that?

Comment: Indeed they are different but alongwith them there is also a comma, space and "reload" which is not correct. If you want to assign an ID then it should be id="changeImage4" or id="changeImage5".

Comment: can i set 2 ids that way?? in the same img?  Change image and reload is javascript functions.. so i need them both!

Comment: No. HTML elements can have only one unique id. Better use classes

Comment: Still cant make it work can i hide somehow the slider?